# polynomials modulo even numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, ideals

> Say I have $R= \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $A = \{p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+\cdots+p_nx^n \mid n\geqslant0, p_i\in\mathbb{Z}, p_0, p_1 \text{ even}\}$. Define $K=R/A$. How would I characterize the elements of $K$?

***What I tried:***

Since the only difference between the sequences of R and A is on $p_0$ and $p_1x$ (A has the extra condition that $p_0$ and $p_1$ need to be even), I concluded that in $R/A$ all that was left were the polynomials of the form:

p(x)=($p_0+p_1x$) where all values of $p_0$ and $p_1$ are in modulo (even numbers).

Looking at the positive integers that would leave me with 0 and 1 as possible values for $p_0$ and $p_1$ giving me the polynomials:

$0+0x$, $0+x$, $1+0x$, $1+x$

***What I am wondering:***

What about the negative integers?

Surely $-1 \mod (2) = 1$

but what about $-1 \mod (even integers)$? (-2 is still an even integer) and

$-1 \mod(-2) = -1$

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to say this but this post is nearly incomprehensible to me.

Comment: $A$ ist just the ideal generated by $2$ and $x^2$. Hence $K=R/A=\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^2)=\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2)=\{0,1,x,1+x\}$. But you should definitely clarify, what you mean $M$ to be...

Comment: @Jake Does the question make more sense now?

Comment: @MooS I am not sure I follow why A is generated by $2$ and $x^2$? how come $x$ does not play a part?

Comment: $2x$ is automatically contained in $A$, since $2 \in A$...

Comment: @Moos yes that is true, could you also clarify the confusion I have in my second part regarding the negative integers?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have concluded and had confirmed by a TA, is that the polynomials:

$-1-x$, $0-x$ and $-1+0x$

are also part of the elements of $K$
This stems from my earlier suspicion that indeed $mod(even integers)$ also includes $mod(-2)$.

(if anyone would like to dispute this conclusion I will leave it here for a day before I accept it as the answer)

Comment: Modulo-ing is generally done with respect to an ideal (i.e. it's not "something you enter on a calculator"), and the ideals $(-2)$, $(2)$, and the even integers are the same.